# Deploy Airflow to Docker from source code

Tags: docker, dockerfile, airflow

I have cloned Airflow repo https://github.com/apache/airflow to local and trying to build to run in docker later to Azure.

I am not sure about the process. I am getting an error

> ERROR [airflow-build-image 11/12] RUN if [[ apache-airflow == "." ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/compile_www_assets.sh;     fi;     if [[   2.5s**

[image]

---------------------- Modifying question ------------------
Installed ubuntu (WSL2) on windows and cloned airflow repo and started building the docker image. I am on **main** branch.

```
docker build . -f Dockerfile --tag airflow-image-20210913:0.0.1
```

Console error:

```
    admin@Laptop-1:~/airflow$ docker build . -f Dockerfile --tag airflow-image-20210913:0.0.1
    [+] Building 41.4s (19/26)
    => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.2s
    => => transferring dockerfile: 21.40kB                                                                            0.0s
    => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
    => => transferring context: 3.14kB                                                                                0.0s
    => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.6-slim-buster                                         24.4s
    => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.1s
    => => transferring context: 40.64kB                                                                               0.0s
    => [airflow-build-image  1/12] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.6-slim-buster@sha256:760b66a8a90751b711bf20243c02  0.0s
    => CACHED [main  2/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends            curl       0.0s
    => CACHED [main  3/11] RUN mkdir -pv /usr/share/man/man1     && mkdir -pv /usr/share/man/man7     && export       0.0s
    => CACHED [main  4/11] COPY scripts/docker/install_mysql.sh scripts/docker/install_pip_version.sh /scripts/docke  0.0s
    => CACHED [main  5/11] RUN chmod a+x /scripts/docker/install_mysql.sh &&     /scripts/docker/install_mysql.sh pr  0.0s
    => CACHED [airflow-build-image  2/12] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends        0.0s
    => CACHED [airflow-build-image  3/12] RUN mkdir -pv /usr/share/man/man1     && mkdir -pv /usr/share/man/man7      0.0s
    => CACHED [airflow-build-image  4/12] COPY scripts/docker/*.sh /scripts/docker/                                   0.0s
    => CACHED [airflow-build-image  5/12] RUN bash ./scripts/docker/install_mysql.sh dev                              0.0s
    => [airflow-build-image  6/12] COPY docker-context-files /docker-context-files                                    0.1s
    => [airflow-build-image  7/12] RUN if [[ -f /docker-context-files/.pypirc ]]; then         cp /docker-context-fi  0.8s
    => [airflow-build-image  8/12] RUN bash /scripts/docker/install_pip_version.sh;     if [[ false == "true" &&     12.0s
    => [airflow-build-image  9/12] COPY empty /empty                                                                  0.1s
    => [airflow-build-image 10/12] WORKDIR /opt/airflow                                                               0.2s
    => ERROR [airflow-build-image 11/12] RUN if [[ apache-airflow == "." ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/compi  3.2s
    ------
    > [airflow-build-image 11/12] RUN if [[ apache-airflow == "." ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/compile_www_assets.sh;     fi;     if [[  == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_from_docker_context_files.sh;     elif [[ true == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_airflow.sh;     fi;     if [[ -n "" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_additional_dependencies.sh;     fi;     find /root/.local/ -name '*.pyc' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true ;     find /root/.local/ -type d -name '__pycache__' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true ;     find /root/.local -executable -print0 | xargs --null chmod g+x;     find /root/.local -print0 | xargs --null chmod g+rw:
    #19 0.669 + [[ apache-airflow == \. ]]
    #19 0.669 + [[ '' == \t\r\u\e ]]
    #19 0.669 + [[ true == \t\r\u\e ]]
    #19 0.669 + bash /scripts/docker/install_airflow.sh
    #19 0.675 + common::get_airflow_version_specification
    #19 0.675 + [[ -z '' ]]
    #19 0.675 + [[ -n 2.2.0.dev0 ]]
    #19 0.675 + [[ apache-airflow != \. ]]
    #19 0.676 + AIRFLOW_VERSION_SPECIFICATION===2.2.0.dev0
    #19 0.676 + common::override_pip_version_if_needed
    #19 0.676 + [[ -n 2.2.0.dev0 ]]
    #19 0.676 + [[ 2.2.0.dev0 =~ ^2\.0.* ]]
    #19 0.676 + [[ 2.2.0.dev0 =~ ^1\.* ]]
    #19 0.676 + common::get_constraints_location
    #19 0.676 + [[ -z '' ]]
    #19 0.676 + [[ 2.2.0.dev0 =~ v?2.* ]]
    #19 0.676 + AIRFLOW_CONSTRAINTS_REFERENCE=constraints-2.2.0.dev0
    #19 0.676 + [[ -z '' ]]
    #19 0.676 + local constraints_base=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.0.dev0
    #19 0.676 + local python_version
    #19 0.678 ++ cut -d ' ' -f 2
    #19 0.678 ++ python --version
    #19 0.682 ++ cut -d . -f 1-2
    #19 0.686 + python_version=3.6
    #19 0.689
    #19 0.689 Installing all packages with constraints and upgrade if needed
    #19 0.689
    #19 0.690 + AIRFLOW_CONSTRAINTS_LOCATION=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.0.dev0/constraints-3.6.txt
    #19 0.690 + install_airflow
    #19 0.690 + [[ apache-airflow != \. ]]
    #19 0.690 + [[ '' == \-\-\e\d\i\t\a\b\l\e ]]
    #19 0.690 + [[ true != \t\r\u\e ]]
    #19 0.690 + [[ false != \f\a\l\s\e ]]
    #19 0.690 + echo
    #19 0.690 + echo Installing all packages with constraints and upgrade if needed
    #19 0.690 + echo
    #19 0.690 + pip install --user 'apache-airflow[async,amazon,celery,cncf.kubernetes,docker,dask,elasticsearch,ftp,grpc,hashicorp,http,ldap,google,google_auth,microsoft.azure,mysql,pandas,postgres,redis,sendgrid,sftp,slack,ssh,statsd,virtualenv]==2.2.0.dev0' --constraint https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.0.dev0/constraints-3.6.txt
    #19 2.227 ERROR: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.0.dev0/constraints-3.6.txt
    ------
    executor failed running [/bin/bash -o pipefail -e -u -x -c if [[ ${AIRFLOW_INSTALLATION_METHOD} == "." ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/compile_www_assets.sh;     fi;     if [[ ${INSTALL_FROM_DOCKER_CONTEXT_FILES} == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_from_docker_context_files.sh;     elif [[ ${INSTALL_FROM_PYPI} == "true" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_airflow.sh;     fi;     if [[ -n "${ADDITIONAL_PYTHON_DEPS}" ]]; then         bash /scripts/docker/install_additional_dependencies.sh;     fi;     find /root/.local/ -name '*.pyc' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true ;     find /root/.local/ -type d -name '__pycache__' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r || true ;     find /root/.local -executable -print0 | xargs --null chmod g+x;     find /root/.local -print0 | xargs --null chmod g+rw]: exit code: 1
```

--------------------- Edit -3 ----------------

I am on python 3.8 and did the build and install successfully but getting error while calling **airflow**

[image]

Comment: Please post your `Dockerfile`

Comment: I am using the one from repo https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/Dockerfile

Comment: If you are using the official Dockerfile without modification, you can just clone from the Dockerhub here https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow instead of building the same image.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I would like to do some code changes. OR a logo change and build the image on the changes. I am using a Windows machine and I have Docker Desktop got installed.

Comment: Your latest error looks like dependency problem. Maybe pandas is not supported / installable on Windows system for your exact version of python.

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown the whole error message. Also you did not post what command you used, what operating system you have and what is your filesystem/Docker engine. All those things matter.

The real error is likely below. I believe the problem is that you are building it on windows and your system does not support executable flag. Build it on WSL2 or Linux VM and it should work just fine.

If you get the remainder of the message, I might even be able to fix it so that it also runs on Windows. so feel free to update it and ping me on Airflow Slack or here if you dump the whole error message you have.

BTW. There is a whole chapter about building your custom image here using the airflow dockerfile: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#customizing-the-image

Comment: Hi @Jarek Potiuk, I have started building the docker image on Ubuntu (WSL2).
I am on main branch of my local airflow git and I tried this command.
docker build . -f Dockerfile --tag airflow-image:0.0.1

I am getting this error:

ERROR: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.2.0.dev0/constraints-3.6.txt

Comment: main branch does not work for building image this way - you should use a specific version of Airflow to install because Airflow 2.2.0 is not yet released. Use the tag for release, or pass version by passing airflow version ``--build-arg AIRFLOW_VERSION="2.1.3"``

Comment: Thanks, @Jarek Potiuk for your comments. Have set the airflow version to env level and getting a panda dependency error. I am adding a screenshot to the description of the question.